# Why can't I do a $scope update within a jQuery scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using typeahead to get some suggestions on an input text, this is inside a div *controlled* by an Angular controller.

The code for the suggestion tasks works with a jQuery plugin, so when I select, something I'm trying to assign a value to $scope, however this is NEVER happening.

I already tried getting the scope of the element with `var scope = angular.element($("#providersSearchInput").scope()` [and then assign it as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113157/angularjs-scope-update-when-i-change-a-select-with-jquery) but it didn't work.

This is what I'm trying:

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-controller="ProvidersController" ng-init="orderReviewTab = 'observations'">

    <input type="text" id="providersSearchInput" data-provide="typeahead" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Buscar proovedores">
    {{currentProvider}}
</div>
```

The controller looks like this:

```
tv3App.controller('ProvidersController', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $timeout) {


  var resultsCache = [];

  $("#providersSearchInput").typeahead({
    source:     function (query, process) {
                  return $.get("/search/providers/?query=" + query, function (results) {
                    resultsCache = results;
                    return process(results);
                  },'json');
                },
    matcher:    function (item) {
                  var name = item.name.toLowerCase();
                  var email = item.email.toLowerCase();
                  var contact_name = item.contact_name.toLowerCase();
                  //console.log(name);
                  var q = this.query.toLowerCase();
                  return (name.indexOf(q) != -1 || email.indexOf(q) != -1 || contact_name.indexOf(q) != -1);
                },
    scrollHeight: 20,
    highlighter: function (itemName) {
      var selected = _.find(resultsCache,{name:itemName});
      var div = $('<div></div>');
      var name = $('<span ></span>').html('<strong style="font-weight:bold">Empresa: </strong> ' + selected.name);
      var contact = $('<span ></span>').html('  <strong style="font-weight:bold">Contacto: </strong> ' + selected.contact_name);
      var email = $('<span ></span>').html('  <strong style="font-weight:bold">e-mail:</strong> ' + selected.email);

      return $(div).append(name).append(contact).append(email).html();
    },
    minLength:  3,
    items:      15,
    afterSelect: function (item) {
      console.log(item);
      $scope.$emit('providerSelected',item);
    }
  });

  $scope.$on('providerSelected', function (event,provider) {
    console.log(provider);
    $scope.currentProvider = provider;
    $scope.$apply();
  });

});
```

### Edit

I tried this to check any changes:

```
  $scope.$watch('currentProvider',function (newValue,oldValue) {
    console.log(oldValue);
    console.log(newValue);
  });
```

So when selecting something it actually triggers and $scope.currentProvider seems to be updated but its never getting rendered at view ...

Comment: Why dont you use ui-bootstrap they have a much better implementation of angular and bootstrap typeahead

Comment: @YangLi could you provide a translation of my typeahead implementation to one with ui-bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

once you do, in your code make sure

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

and for typeahead have

```
<input type="text" ng-model="currentProvider" typeahead="provider for provider in getProviders($viewValue) | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

In your controller make sure you have

```
$scope.getProviders = function(val){
    return $http.get('/search/providers/?query=' + val).then(function(response){
        return response.data;
    })
}
```

This should do the trick although I haven't tested