# how to make a global variable that can be accessed by my html,angularjs and jquery file

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on an UI which consist of binding of angularjs,html and jquery.
Is there a way i can declare a gloabal variable that is accesed in all three files.

Comment: Use `window.myVar = something`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using browserify or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) (I highly recommend it), you could have a config file that you simply require where appropriate:

```
// config.json

module.exports = {
  "some": "important config value"
}

// some-random-file.js

var config = require('config.json');

var some = config.some; // => 'important config value'
```

Even cooler-looking with [babel](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader):

```
export default {
  "some": "important config value"
}

// some-file.js

import config from 'config.json';

const some = config.some; // => 'important config value'
```

I think in general you probably want to avoid setting any "globally available" variables on the Window object, because there can be many much cleaner implementations. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Any angular scope variable can be bound with HTML, Jquery or Angular. Just be aware that the JQuery loads first and of course what actual scope you are working within.

[angular js: accessing $scope from jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877008/angular-js-accessing-scope-from-jquery)
[angularjs: $scope update when I change a select with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113157/angularjs-scope-update-when-i-change-a-select-with-jquery)